# MVCSiteMapProvider DymanicNode RouteValues Confusion

Tags: asp.net, mvcsitemapprovider

I am facing some problem or maybe I am confused. I've followed the following link to generate dynamic Site Map:

[MVCSiteMapProvider Dynamic Sitemap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20sitemaps)

I am confused at `node.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);` in the class given in above link. My website links are not in the form given in the example they discussed (their URLs are like mysite.com/controller?id=some id)

where as my URLs are in following format:

mysite.com/mycontroller/querystring1/querystring2/querystring3

How can I "mention" such kind of URL in `node.RouteValues.Add(..., ...);` so that it should redirect to mysite.com/controller/querystring1/querystring2/querystring3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format of the URLs makes no difference. Either way, they are transformed into a collection of route values, which is what MvcSiteMapProvider uses under the hood.

Therefore, the same line `node.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);` can be used in either scenario to make the node match. The actual processing of the URL into route values is done by .NET routing, not MvcSiteMapProvider.